# Google Analytics User Limitations

Tags: google-analytics, quota, universal-analytics

In the [GA Limits & Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas#universal_properties) documentation, they mention **200,000 hits per user per day** for free Universal Analytics.

Does **per user** mean per GA account in this case, or is it per website user?

I'd assume 200k per website user sounds like an unrealistic limitation to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its per user.

A single user on your web site which is most often denoted by their IP address unless you are sending a userid along with your hits.  can max cause 200,000 hits per day to be created in your google analytics account.

Seriously though think about it 200,000 hits is a lot of hits what do you think a user would be doing to cause that kind of traffic?

Comment: that's why I thought to ask this question if it's per account since creating such a huge limit for a single website user sounds pretty intense.

Comment: It also applies to the measurement protocol, so conceivably this would be relevant for some IOT devices (if you do very granular measurements or something like it). I guess for any real-life user case the 500 hits per session limit is much more relevant.

Comment: It is possible to hit these limits but google makes them large to avoid causing anyone problems.   I suspect the issue is more related to sampling due to the large amounts of data.  There are sites that record a lot of data.   I worked on a site which had hit the million hits a month cap they had to move over to professional GA to get the additional hits.